# Magento empty transactional emails variables

Tags: php, magento, email

All the transactional emails on a store I'm developing are showing empty variable values in emails.
For example, the following is what a new user will get:

> Dear ,
>
> Welcome to MySite. To log in when visiting our site just click Login
>   or My Account at the top of every page, and then enter your e-mail
>   address and password.
>
> Use the following values when prompted to log in: E-mail:  Password:

Note the empty value after "Dear" and no emails or password.
I've checked the exception and system logs but nothing is being logged.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you do a magento update recently or installed a new theme? The password was removed in magento 1.6. Remove the layout file `customer.xml` from your theme and at least the passwort forgot link is sent in the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this fixed, a third-party installed extension was overriding the sendTransactional() incorrectly.

Comment: Which extension? Mailchimp?